# Save an id from a related model on save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this, but the explanation is complex, so please do bear with me.

I have a registration form `Registration::add()` and it comprises of three sections.

1. The first is the `Registration` data, a number of fields.
2. The second is checkboxes from three related `HABTM` models, `Role`, `Category` and `CategoryChild`
3. Third is creating a record in `User`

My `Registration` model has a `user_id` and I need to save the generated `User.id` into that field.

I'm sure that I should be able to do this using the model relationships, as the `User` model saves the `User.registration_id` fine, but it doesn't seem to be writing into the `Registration` model.

Do I need to create another field in my `add.ctp` view so that the field is present in the `$this->data->request` array? I would much rather do this, than get embroiled in faffing with `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()`.

So do I just need to create

```
$this->Form->input('Registration.user_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
```

My relationships, for reference,

```
Registration hasOne User
Registration hasAndBelongsToMany Category
Registration hasAndBelongsToMany CategoryChild
Registration hasAndBelongsToMany Role
User hasOne Registration
```

I'm currently using `saveAll($this->request->data)` to save all my data, and it's managing to save everything except `Registration.user_id`

Comment: Your Relationships specify that `Registration hasOne User` but you have both a `Registration.user_id` and a `User.registration_id`, so something doesn't seem right

Comment: A one to one relationship you mean?

Comment: @icc97 You are right, I've been at it so long I totally missed it. That would explain why my id isn't being updated twice! If you could make that into an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: cheers, duly added :) Do you generate the Models through the Cake Baker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Relationships have

```
Registration hasOne User
```

However you have both a `Registration.user_id` and a `User.registration_id` implying that you need hasAndBelongsToMany relationship.

Just in case you're not using the [Cake Baker](http://www.webdevelopment2.com/cakephp-bake-baking-models-controllers-views-cakephp-12/) to generate the models it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this should work as per your question:

```
<?php echo $form->input('Registration.user_id',array('type'=>'hidden', 'value' => $user_id)); ?>
```

Hope it helps